# LWC component as global action

Tags: lightning-web-components, global-actions

I see option to use lwc as **global** action but there no information about how to configure xml to be able use component.
[image: setup]

Comment: I could only get an Aura component to show up in that UI and perhaps. LWCs do now work for Object actions. (Sorry to waste your time with the answer I've now deleted.)

Comment: It seems this is part of Winter '23 Release. I could see the Component in the dropdown using 'lightning__GlobalAction' as target, but the Action is not visible in the Global Action menu even after adding in the Publisher  Layout.

Comment: @SarojBera, I would add your comment as the answer. Setting my component to API version 56 allowed it to be selected here.

Comment: @nbrown, please add.

Answer (score 5):

Add the target of lightning__GlobalAction

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
        <target>lightning__GlobalAction</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__GlobalAction">
        <actionType>Action</actionType>
      </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Can you add documentation @viva-la-cubs

Comment: this worked for getting my LWC to show up as an option when i create a new action.  My LWC will not show up in the global header after adding to publisher layout, but that may be because the LWC launches a screen flow, which just came out in [W23.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_lwc_launch_screen_flows.htm&type=5&release=240)

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Even after setting target to 'lightning__GlobalAction' and actiontype to 'ScreenAction', the LWC is only available in the options of global action however it is not displayed in the global actions despite adding it in the publisher layout .

**Solution :**
I created an Aura component for Quick actions, then I embedded the LWC in the Aura component I just created. Finally, I created a global action with the Aura component and added it to the publisher layout.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/use-config-for-quick-actions.html), a lightning web component can be added as a quick action on record pages only. LWC **cannot** be used as a global quick action. Aura is the only way around this.