# Field Service Mobile Application

Tags: apex, field-service-lightning, fieldservice, salesforce-mobile-app, light-application-object

I am trying to add a lightning component in Field Service Mobile app using Global action.

- I've added a global action using my custom lightning component.
- And then added that action in Publisher Layouts in Lightning action but still it is not showing in mobile App.
- Although i've added a pre-defined Candidates Visualforce page as well but not showing up.
- And when i remove some actions like New Opportunity/New Lead etc. it removed successfully.
  Don't know what's the actual problem
  Please suggest me where do i activate this or correct me if i am doing anything wrong. or let me know if there's any limitation for application.

Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to add actions to the first menu (Quick Actions in the Salesforce Classic Publisher) for them to appear in the Salesforce Field Service Mobile App, instead of the second menu where your circles are.

Answer (score 0):

I think FSL only support Lightning Web Component quick actions for now

Answer (score 0):

This may have been covered in [LWC component as global action](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/384161/lwc-component-as-global-action) which shows how to wrap an Aura component (and I'm sure you can find docs for wrapping a VF page) in a LWC component. That should let you use that as your Action.

Answer (score 0):

Add the target as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
   <isExposed>true</isExposed>
   <targets>
        <target>lightning__GlobalAction</target>
   </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
   <targetConfig targets="lightning__GlobalAction">
        <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
      </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

actionType as 'Action' won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add targets:

```
 <targets>
        <target>lightning__GlobalAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
```